# How to aggregate hystrix metrics in clusters with turbine when using spring cloud stream

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, turbine, spring-cloud-stream

We would like to change our hystrix/turbine setup to use spring-cloud-stream (with a Kafka bus). The changes are quite simple and I can see all my hystrix circuits and metrics in the dashboard ... but my cluster grouping doesn't work anymore...

In the older setup, I would have the following property in my `boostrap.yml` :

```
eureka.metadataMap.turbineCluster: my-cluster-name
```

and my turbine config would have something like that :

```
turbine.clusterNameExpression: metadata['turbineCluster']
```

I figure that, since we are now using the kafka bus, eureka is not used anymore and that this is moot, but I can't figure out how to set a cluster name  now ... I could maybe prefix the appname with a cluster name and use a clusterNameExpression to extract the prefix, but maybe there is something simpler I can do ... any idea ?

edit 1 : I can not use a clusterNameExpression ... they are not available in spring-cloud-starter-turbine-stream...

edit 2 : it looks as if spring-cloud-starter-turbine-stream uses Turbine 2, whereas the spring-cloud-starter-turbine uses Turbine 1. Turbine 2 is really different in terms of config...

Comment: spring-cloud-starter-turbine-stream doesn't support clusters yet.

Comment: ok, thanks @spencergibb. That's what I thought after looking at the code. I like the "yet" in that sentence :)

Comment: there's an open issue

Comment: for anyone following, there is the issue : https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/166

Comment: @Sébastien Nussbaumer:
I want to ask you a question.The detail is：
[my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42644513/how-to-aggregate-hystrix-metrics-with-turbine-stream-and-kafka-when-using-spring)