# How to aggregate hystrix metrics with turbine-stream and kafka when using spring cloud?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-stream

When I aggregate hystrix metrics in clusters with turbine when using spring cloud stream and kafka stream.
I encountered the following error：

```
  
2017-03-07 16:54:57.519  INFO 12808 --- [o-eventloop-3-1] o.s.c.n.t.s.TurbineStreamConfiguration   : SSE Request Received
2017-03-07 16:54:57.519  INFO 12808 --- [o-eventloop-3-2] o.s.c.n.t.s.TurbineStreamConfiguration   : SSE Request Received
2017-03-07 16:55:04.121  INFO 12808 --- [o-eventloop-3-3] o.s.c.n.t.s.TurbineStreamConfiguration   : Unsubscribing RxNetty server connection
2017-03-07 16:55:04.122  INFO 12808 --- [o-eventloop-3-4] o.s.c.n.t.s.TurbineStreamConfiguration   : Unsubscribing RxNetty server connection
2017-03-07 16:55:09.020  INFO 12808 --- [afka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Marking the coordinator 192.168.10.90:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) dead for group anonymous.7766322c-4113-4a21-a441-aebbff3ca6e3
2017-03-07 16:55:09.129  INFO 12808 --- [afka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Discovered coordinator 192.168.10.90:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) for group anonymous.7766322c-4113-4a21-a441-aebbff3ca6e3.
2017-03-07 16:55:09.130  INFO 12808 --- [afka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : (Re-)joining group anonymous.7766322c-4113-4a21-a441-aebbff3ca6e3
2017-03-07 16:55:49.237  INFO 12808 --- [afka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : (Re-)joining group anonymous.7766322c-4113-4a21-a441-aebbff3ca6e3
2017-03-07 16:56:17.367  INFO 12808 --- [o-eventloop-3-3] o.s.c.n.t.s.TurbineStreamConfiguration   : SSE Request Received
2017-03-07 16:56:24.119  INFO 12808 --- [o-eventloop-3-2] o.s.c.n.t.s.TurbineStreamConfiguration   : Unsubscribing RxNetty server connection
2017-03-07 16:56:24.558  INFO 12808 --- [afka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Marking the coordinator 192.168.10.90:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) dead for group anonymous.7766322c-4113-4a21-a441-aebbff3ca6e3
2017-03-07 16:56:24.663  INFO 12808 --- [afka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Discovered coordinator 192.168.10.90:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) for group anonymous.7766322c-4113-4a21-a441-aebbff3ca6e3.
2017-03-07 16:56:24.663  INFO 12808 --- [afka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : (Re-)joining group anonymous.7766322c-4113-4a21-a441-aebbff3ca6e3
2017-03-07 16:56:43.188  INFO 12808 --- [o-eventloop-3-4] o.s.c.n.t.s.TurbineStreamConfiguration   : SSE Request Received
2017-03-07 16:57:04.773  INFO 12808 --- [afka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : (Re-)joining group anonymous.7766322c-4113-4a21-a441-aebbff3ca6e3
2017-03-07 16:57:27.332  INFO 12808 --- [o-eventloop-3-2] o.s.c.n.t.s.TurbineStreamConfiguration   : SSE Request Received
2017-03-07 16:57:34.120  INFO 12808 --- [o-eventloop-3-1] o.s.c.n.t.s.TurbineStreamConfiguration   : Unsubscribing RxNetty server connection
2017-03-07 16:57:40.235  INFO 12808 --- [afka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Marking the coordinator 192.168.10.90:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) dead for group anonymous.7766322c-4113-4a21-a441-aebbff3ca6e3
2017-03-07 16:57:40.341  INFO 12808 --- [afka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Discovered coordinator 192.168.10.90:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) for group anonymous.7766322c-4113-4a21-a441-aebbff3ca6e3`
```

The turbine log:

```
2017-03-07 17:13:44.123 ERROR 12811 --- [io-10004-exec-2] ashboardConfiguration$ProxyStreamServlet : Error proxying request: http://localhost:8989/turbine.stream

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
```

and in the chrom browser:

```
data: {"type":"Ping"}

data: {"type":"Ping"}

data: {"type":"Ping"}

data: {"type":"Ping"}

data: {"type":"Ping"}

data: {"type":"Ping"}

data: {"type":"Ping"}

data: {"type":"Ping"}

data: {"type":"Ping"}

data: {"type":"Ping"}
```

my spring cloud version is Camden.SR5.

Comment: Can you post your code? read these link to improve your question: [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Tom - Could you pls guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61444872/org-springframework-cloud-netflix-hystrix-dashboard-hystrixdashboardconfiguratio ?